# JS - remove every close html tag from string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I've got such string:

```
var string = '<div class="post-content"></div><div class="post"></div><div id="content" class="col-lg-12"></div><div class="row"></div><div id="container" class="container"></div><body class="page page-id-157 page-template page-template-page-fullwidth-no-sidebar-php logged-in admin-bar  customize-support" style="">';
```

And I want to remove every close tag from it. It may or may not be div.

I've tried `string.replace(/<\/\S+>$/, '');` but it seems to be working only when there is only one tag. For more it does not work at all

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/PQfex/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the global modifier (find all matches instead of only the first), you should also make it non-greedy (Add a `?` after `\S+`). Also remove the `$` as that will only match at the end of the string:

```
string.replace(/<\/\S+?>/g, '');
```

Also note that this will remove tags like `</div>`, but not `</ div>`, since you don't allow whitespace.

Comment: Same here. Am I doing something wrong with your code? http://jsfiddle.net/PQfex/3/

Comment: @Kluska000 Yeah, you also had a `$` in your regex that you don't want. I removed it too.

Answer (score 2):

```
string.replace(/<\/\S+>/g, '');
```

The "g" after the trailing slash means *global*, which means nothing more than replace all instances of the regexp, rather than the first.

Also, that `$` means it will *only* match against the very *last* instance of the expression. Removing that should get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

yep, don't use `$` in:

```
/<\/\S+>$/
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/PQfex/6/)